# Javascript: Load one js-file into another js-file like it was one file

Tags: javascript, frameworks

I'm using babylon.js as a framework for easy access to WebGL. Unfortunetaly, I'm struggling a bit with managing my code.

For example, I want to create a mesh in a js-file, then I want to edit its position in another js-file.

**So what I need is that the index-file loads all javascript-files like their code was written as one large block in the index file.**

Using jQuerys *getScript* for example runs the other js-File, but does not implement it into the code like it was one file.

**EDIT:** using the php-include it works how it should. Just for understanding: The server is creating the output in this case, doesn't it?

Looking forward answers!

Comment: Time to get used to dealing with multiple separate files when you are working with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser interprets JS files as it receives them. In case of jQuery, requireJS or other loaders new  tag is added to the page, so browser loads a new file, and processes it as a new file.

The only way to achieve what you want is to make server compile different files together and give it to browser as one file. This is what PHP does, this is what any other compiler is for (like Grunt).

On a large scale though, it may be a bad idea to write code in different files such as it works differently whether it's loaded as is or compiled to one file. It can be a major pain to support that code later on.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. :)